# Show different heading text on mouseover (flashlight effect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a heading that says one thing but says something different when you mouse over it.

So for example if I had two absolute positioned headings

One appearing over top of the other, both with white text on black backgrounds.

Now I want a circle to appear where the mouse cursor is so that if you were to move it over the "Sa" for example, you would see the letters "Cr" coming through. Kind of like a flashlight effect to reveal the div underneath.

[This is what the heading would look like with no mouseover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo49j.png)

[image]

[With the mouse over the "Sa" - the outline is not needed for the effect, it is just there for visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/indZL.png)

[image]

Thanks in advance!
Jesse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code.

```js
$(function(){
 $(".outer").mousemove(function(e){
   var outer = $(this);
   var cursor = outer.find(".cursor");
    var inner = outer.find(".inner");
    
   var left = e.pageX - outer.offset().left - cursor.outerWidth() / 2;
    var top = e.pageY - outer.offset().top - cursor.outerHeight() / 2;
   
    if (left < 0) {
     left = 0;
    }
    if (top < 0) {
     top = 0;
    }
    if (left + cursor.outerWidth() > outer.outerWidth()) {
     left = outer.outerWidth() - cursor.outerWidth();
    }
    if (top + cursor.outerHeight() > outer.outerHeight()) {
     top = outer.outerHeight() - cursor.outerHeight();
    }   
    
    cursor.show().css({left: left, top: top});
    inner.css({left: -left, top: -top});
  }).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).find(".cursor").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.outer{position: relative;cursor: none;}
.outer, .inner{width: 300px;padding: 20px;font-size: 30px;background: #000;color: #fff;text-align: center;font-style: italic;}
.cursor, .inner{position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;}
.cursor{width: 50px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;border-radius: 50%;box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  Abcde Fghij
  <div class="cursor"><div class="inner">Klmno Pqrst</div></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sasikumar3/pbva9qmb/)

Comment: looks great..+1

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you so much! This is exactly what I am looking for! Very cool solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this sample code.

```
<body>
<h3>Welcome</h3>
</body>


h3:hover{
font-size:150%;
color: blue; 
}

h3:hover:before{
content:"Hello!";
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Please provide full example so we can test this on live.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This doesn't seem to work, it simply changes the text and doesn't really reveal anything.

What I am hoping to achieve is to have a round cut out in a top div to reveal the text on the bottom div underneath if that makes sense? Ideally it would also animate a little, as if the mouse was clearing away the top div somehow (but that is just an ideal).

Comment: I guess another way to do it would be to have the top div invisible and then just show a circle of it wherever the mouse is. Maybe that would be easier?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit of JavaScript and the `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` attributes.

Do something like

```js
function entered(){
 document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="Cr";
}
function left(){
 document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="Sa";
}
```

```html
<body>
 <span id="change" onmouseenter="entered()" onmouseleave="left()">Sa</span>cred spaces
</body>
```

When mouse comes over the "Sa", the function `entered()` is called to make it "Cr" and when mouse leaves it `left()` is called to restore it.

The id `change` and `<span>` tag are used to identify the part of document that needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is an interesting solution for sure and I could play around with it since it may work as a short term solution. What I am hoping to achieve is to have a cut out in a div to reveal the text underneath if that makes sense? Ideally it would also animate a little, as if the mouse was clearing away the top div somehow (but that is just an ideal).